# Application of Gronwall's lemma

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Use **Gronwall's lemma** to prove that the IVP
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{\sin t}y(t),~y(0)=y_{0}~~~(*),$$
with $y_0$ being given, has an infinite interval of existence for its solutions.

My approach: Gronwall's lemma states that

> Suppose that $g(t)$ is a continuous real-valued function that satisfies $g(t) \geq 0$ and 
>   $$g(t) \leq C+K \int_{0}^{t} g(s)~ds$$
>   for all $t \in [0,a],$ where $C$ and $K$ are positive constants.  It then follows that 
>   $$g(t) \leq C e^{Kt},~~\textrm{for all}~t \in [0,a].$$

Solving $(*)$ we get 
$$y(t)=y_0 \cdot e^{ \int_{0}^{t} e^{\sin s}~ds}.$$
How can I set up an inequality for this and apply Gronwall's to conclude what's being asked ? What I'm understanding is existence of an infinite interval means that the solution exists for all values of $t.$ Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{\sin t}y(t),~y(0)=y_{0}$$

$$\implies y(t)=y(0)+\int_0^t\exp(\sin(t))y(s)\,ds$$

$$\implies |y(t)|\le |y_0|+e\int_0^t|y(s)|\,ds$$

Applying Gronwall:

$$|y(t)|\le |y_0|\cdot\exp(et)$$

So, $y$ cannot blow up to $\infty$ in finite time, as it is bounded above by an exponential function.

Comment: Or that was easy. :( I shouldn't have solved it the way that I did. Thank you.

Comment: So if solved it the way that I did, there's no way to get the desired result right ?

Comment: You could just say that $\exp(\int_0^t \exp(\sin(s))\,ds)\le exp(et)$ by making effectively the same comparison - the idea is to use some expression to guarantee that the solution won't become singular.

Comment: I see. Sticking into the set up of Gronwall's is much easier.